# How to convert ElementRef to NgModel

Tags: angular

I've simplified an existing logic, so excuse the vagueness of the implementation and don't read too much into the validity of using ngDoCheck(). I'm simply trying to understand how to capture NgModel in the component.ts file.

#### html

```html
<!-- Existing code -->
<div>
  <input #local ngModel 
  #ref="ngModel" 
  (keyup)="validate(ref)"/>

</div>

Print: {{ref.value}}
```

#### ts

```js
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('ref', { static: true }) ref: ElementRef;

  ngDoCheck() { //My Method
    this.validate(this.ref);  //ERROR: type 'ElementRef<any>' and not 'NgModel'. 
                                //Question is how can I get ngModel type here?
  }

  public validate(mymodel: NgModel){//Existing code. Can't modify signature.
    console.log(mymodel.value);
    //do something
  }
}
```

**Assume that I can't change the validate method signature.**
I want to be able to capture the 'NgModel' of the 'input' element within ngDoCheck(). Is it possible?

Comment: Frankly, this is the wrong way to do validation. Your life would be a lot easier if you used the validation framework provided by reactive forms (which template driven forms uses under the hood, so it should be accessible). As pointed out by the answer, you can't gurantee ngOnChanges will fire at teh times you want, in fact it will fire when any input to the component changes (as well as on component initialization).

Comment: I'm not looking for usage on ngOnChanges() or how to do validation. I simply need to know if it's possible to capture NgModel instead of ElementRef. I've changed the code so these questions don't come up again. Appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be as simple as typecasting to 'NgModel' instead of 'ElementRef',

```js
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('ref', { static: true }) ref: NgModel; //WORKED

  ngDoCheck() { //My Method
    this.validate(this.ref);
  }

  public validate(mymodel: NgModel){//Existing code. Can't modify signature.
    console.log(mymodel.value);
    //do something
  }
}
```

Another point to note, using ***#local did not work*** as expected. A number of undefined errors.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('local', { static: true }) local: NgModel; //Did not work as expected

  ngDoCheck() { //My Method
    this.validate(this.local);  //Did not work as expected. undefined errors.
  }

  public validate(mymodel: NgModel){//Existing code. Can't modify signature.
    console.log(mymodel.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use different way:

```
<div>
  <input
    ngModel 
    #ref
    (keyup)="validate()"/>
</div>
```

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('ref', { static: true, read: NgControl }) ref: NgControl;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.validate(); 
  }

  public validate() {
    console.log(this.ref.value);
    console.log("Validated");
  }
}
```

There are some problems in your code:

- inside ngOnChanges you can not use this.ref, because at this moment there is no view, so this.ref will be empty, so it's better to switch to ngAfterViewInit, when you will have ref link
- there is special directive NgControl, that allows to work with FormControl, so you can get FormControl from template through `read: NgControl`

working example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mdd8bi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: ngOnChanges() is triggered when required without issue. This sample is just an abstraction of an elaborate implementation. I'm looking for a solution without changing the signature on 'validate' method.